# Adding customized functions to Buildbot

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

I have written a function in python and I would like to have Buildbot to execute this function
when it receives a "build" command. I have used the "factory.addStep()" before to add new commands through command line, but I'm not sure how I can add a python function to Buildbot. Thanks and please let me know if I'm being unclear on anything.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want the code to run on the master or the slave?

If you want to run code on the master, then all you need to do is subclass `BuildStep`, and put your code in `.start` (see the link in vernomcrp's answer).

If you want to run the code on the slave, things become trickier. The simplest solution is if you can write a python script (rather than function), and execute that script. You can include the script in your repository, or download it to the slave with [`FileDownload`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#transferring-files) or [`StringDownload`](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#transfering-strings).

If you require the code to run in the slave process it self, you need patch the slave, to add a new command, *and* create a corresponding `BuildStep` on the master, that calls your new command. This requires modifying the buildslave code on *all* slaves that you want to run the code on. This isn't documented anywhere, so you will need to have a look at the code to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can customize buildstep to execute python function. Have a look at this link http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/manual/customization.html. I think it has something what you want. :)